# SQL code security

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, security, optimization

I am wanting to use a MYSQL database that is online and mainly accesseded via a desktop and maybe a cell phone application. I am wanting someone to please have a quick look at my code and tell me what needs to be changed/improved in relation to security. Basically, can my code be improved or should it be changed?

Here is my code:

```
Create Database db_person_cdtest;

USE [db_person_cdtest]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [Person](
[PersonID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ID] [varchar](20),
[FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[AddressLine1] [varchar](50),
[AddressLine2] [varchar](50),
[AddressLine3] [varchar](50),
[MobilePhone] [varchar](20),
[HomePhone] [varchar](20),
[Description] [varchar](10),
[DateModified] [datetime],
[PersonCategory] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[Comment] [varchar](max),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[PersonID] DESC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertPerson
(
@ID VARCHAR(20),
@FirstName VARCHAR(50),
@LastName VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine3 VARCHAR(50),
@MobilePhone VARCHAR(20),
@HomePhone VARCHAR(20),
@Description VARCHAR(10),
@Comment VARCHAR(max)
)

AS

BEGIN
Declare @PersonCategory VARCHAR(30)
SET @PersonCategory = dbo.usp_PersonCategoryLookup(@ID, @Description)
INSERT INTO Person(ID, FirstName, LastName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, MobilePhone, HomePhone, Description, DateModified, PersonCategory, Comment)
VALUES (@ID, @FirstName, @LastName, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @AddressLine3, @MobilePhone, @HomePhone, @Description, GETDATE (), @PersonCategory, @Comment)
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdatePerson
(
@PersonID numeric(18, 0),
@ID VARCHAR(20),
@FirstName VARCHAR(50),
@LastName VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50),
@AddressLine3 VARCHAR(50),
@MobilePhone VARCHAR(20),
@HomePhone VARCHAR(20),
@Description VARCHAR(10),
@Comment VARCHAR(max)
)

AS

BEGIN
    Declare @PersonCategory VARCHAR(30)
SET @PersonCategory = dbo.usp_PersonCategoryLookup(@ID, @Description)
Update Person set ID=@ID, FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, AddressLine1=@AddressLine1, AddressLine2=@AddressLine2, AddressLine3=@AddressLine3, MobilePhone=@MobilePhone, HomePhone=@HomePhone, Description=@Description, DateModified=GETDATE (), PersonCategory=@PersonCategory, Comment=@Comment where PersonID=@PersonID
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SearchPerson
(
@SearchCriteria VARCHAR(50)
)

AS

BEGIN
Select * from Person where FirstName like @SearchCriteria or LastName like @SearchCriteria or PersonCategory like @SearchCriteria
END

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SelectPerson
(
@PersonID numeric(18, 0)
)

AS

BEGIN
select * from Person where PersonID=@PersonID
END

CREATE FUNCTION usp_PersonCategoryLookup
(
@ID VARCHAR(20),
@Description VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS

BEGIN
    return @ID + @Description
END
```

Comment: If you are using a MySQL database, why are you writing code using SQL Server conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following columns to the person table:

- CreatedByUser (varchar or int)
- CreatedDateTime (datetime)
- LastUpdateByUser (varchar or int)
- LastUpdateDateTime (datetime)

This is because, in this way, you can see who is the user who created the record and the user who updated the record the last time, for auditing purposes.

Also, although this is not related to security, avoid using the asterisk (*) on the select statements. Place the column names that you want to be returned. This will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: It seems such a common way for people to set things up but I always feel that the `LastUpdateXXX` columns are broken - there might have been 3 people making significant changes to a particular row, and then some poor sap comes along and corrects a simple spelling mistake, and yet they're the person who gets fingered by the `LastUpdateXXX` column. If you need to track updates, track *every* update in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on distributing this application, please be aware that it is possible to easily decompile a .net application and view the source code. This creates a potential for users to get your database connection info and potentially give them access to the full database. You may want to do a little research into properly locking down the user account that is used within this project.

Also, ignore anyone who says to encrypt the connection information and decrypt it at runtime. If you have methods within your code to decrypt at runtime, then whoever decompiles your application will also have these methods. Code obfuscation is another choice but only slows the process, not prevent it.